# O que é um POC em C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, terminologia

Recebi uma solicitação de fazer um POC de e-mail, mas antes de fazê-lo gostaria de saber o que é um POC em C#.

Se existe conteúdo na internet para o mesmo.

P.S: Não quero a solução, só gostaria de saber o que é para pesquisar.

Comment: Pode ser ainda que tenham te pedido um "POG" e pode ter havido confusão na escrita ou entendimento porque a pronúncia é parecida. POG é bem popular também e significa "Programação Orientada a Gambiarra", que é quando qualquer solução, desde que seja entregue rápido e que funcione uma vez, serve. Lembrando que POG não é um paradigma reconhecido na esfera profissinoal, por assim dizer :D Sugestão: pergunte para quem escreveu o que significa a sigla - nenhum profissional é obrigado a conhecer previamente ou memorizar nenhuma sigla.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

Não dá para ter certeza sem saber o contexto, mas acho que não seja algo específico de C#. Eu imagino que seja [*proof of concept*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prova_de_conceito), ou seja te pediram para fazer algo prático que mostre que é possível realizar uma teoria. Pode ser que pediram para fazer algo simples, que tenha funcionamento básico e que não precisa estar pronto para uso em produção. Pode ser considerado um protótipo para futuro desenvolvimento ou para avaliar melhor a estratégia a ser adotada.

O termo pode ser equivocadamente empregado para solicitar uma prova de conhecimento ao invés de prova de conceito. Podem ter pedido para mostrar se você sabe fazer um software que execute uma determinada tarefa.

Note que pode não ser nada disto, é difícil falar sobre o sigla que alguém usou e que não seja frequentemente empregada. E ainda parto do princípio que ela está correta.

Se for C# seria POCO (Plain Old C# Object) que é um objeto que tem só o seu domínio e não tem mecanismos extras como manipulação de banco de dados por exemplo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).